# Robô para realizar procedimentos web semelhante a PhantomJS

Tags: c#, abot

Existe algum framework ou forma de implementação para navegar por um website programaticamente através de código c#?

Estudei os frameworks `phantomJS` e `Selenium`, mas estes possuem algumas limitações em relação a navegação dinâmica, como adicionar scripts em tempo de execução, modificar variáveis e a árvore DOM, capturar imagens (screenshot) e recuperar o HTML.

Também estudei utilizar a classe `HttpWebRequest` e `HttpWebResponse` mas algumas interações precisam ser realizadas em formulários WEB, e até onde pesquisei não consegui realizar o submit de um formulário como se estivesse navegando realmente na página.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Existe algum framework ou forma de implementação para navegar por um website programaticamente através de código c#?

Sim. [O Abot faz isso](https://github.com/sjdirect/abot).

[O pacote NuGet dele está aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Abot/).

Comment: é possível executar scripts em Javascript com o Abot?

Comment: Sim, [veja este link](https://abotx.org/Learn/JavascriptRendering).

Comment: é possível realizar um click em um botão utilizando o Abot? É necessário outra pergunta para esta resposta?

Comment: É possível. Não sei se precisa outra pergunta. Aí é com você.

Comment: abri uma nova pergunta a respeito do clique após algumas pesquisas feitas. Deixo o link aqui para quem tiver a mesma necessidade http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101397/como-alterar-o-dom-e-efetuar-click-utilizando-abot

Comment: Só ler a documentação

Comment: Não encontrei na documentação uma simulação do click em um botão capturado no CrawledPage, @Rod, por isso perguntei se era possível efetuar este evento.

Comment: @JoãoPauloMassa qual a sua finalidade ? Deseja fazer o que exatamente? Conheço outra opção do Abot, e faz os eventos de click, por exemplo

Comment: @Rod, a finalidade maior é navegar no meu website como um usuário final (através de um robô), realizando as mesmas interações que um usuário comum pode realizar. Por se tratar de um robô, não há  a necessidade de haver uma interface de visualização (como o phantomJS)

Comment: @JoãoPaulo, você conseguiu fazer o que vc queria, a sua navegação programatica? Estou querendo desenvolver uma tambem porem em PHP e estou coletando informações para dar inicio.

Comment: @ValentimAraújo, utilizei o Selenium com a API do C#. Ele permite um nível bem detalhado de navegação. Até o momento o único limitador que encontrei foi precisar de um browser com interface, uma vez que a biblioteca para PhantomJS está descontinuada e sem atualizações.