# Como alterar o DOM e efetuar click utilizando ABOT

Tags: c#, abot

Como posso capturar o retorno de uma requisição de um botão `submit` utilizando `Abot`?

Com o código abaixo consigo pesquisar através da `árvore DOM`, modificar os valores dos meus `inputs` e capturar o elemento que efetua o submit do formulário (ou o próprio formulário). Contudo, não consigo prosseguir e realizar uma outra requisição para avaliar seu retorno.

Como posso realizar este processo?

```
        void crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted(object sender, PageCrawlCompletedArgs e)
        {
            CrawledPage crawledPage = e.CrawledPage;

            var txtFoo = crawledPage.CsQueryDocument["#someId"].First();
            txtFoo.Text("Some text");

            var btnSubmit = crawledPage.CsQueryDocument["#btnSubmit"].First();
        }
```